# How to select child element using BeatifulSoup

Tags: python

[Html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKwfF.png)

How can i select all of titleline href's with using BeatifulSoup ?

Comment: Do you have any code snippets to show?

Comment: please don't use images... copy those few lines and add them to the question

Answer (score 0):

Given soup as a BeautifilSoup object of your website, try this:

```
soup.find("span", {"class": "titleline"}).findChildren("a")
```

edit:

```
[a['href'] for elem in soup.find_all("span", {"class": "titleline"}) for a in elem.findChildren("a")]
```

Full example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://news.ycombinator.com/news")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

hrefs = [a['href'] for elem in soup.find_all("span", {"class": "titleline"}) for a in elem.findChildren("a")]
```

filter:

```
hrefs = [a['href'] 
         for elem in soup.find_all("span", {"class": "titleline"}) 
         for a in elem.findChildren("a") 
         if a['href'].startswith("https://")]
```

Comment: thank you but i m trying to take all span's on site so how can I do with 'find_all' or something different ?

Comment: Edited, pls try this. If it does not work - can you provide the url?

Comment: https://news.ycombinator.com/news this is the url

Comment: it errors like this ||  articles = [a['href'] for a in elem.findChildren("a") for elem in soup.find_all("span", {"class": "titleline"})]
NameError: name 'elem' is not defined

Comment: Added a full example

Comment: You select both internal and external links. Is that what you want or do you want to filter them somehow?

Comment: can we filter only hyperlinks which are work ?

Comment: As a filter you can check if it startswith https -> example as edit

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

```
[i.a.get_attribute('href') for i in soup.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,'titleline)]
```

this list-comp creates a list with all titleline links
but if there is some titleline without href inside an error will emerge